# Perron-Frobenius Theorem. A particular case?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\{a_{i,j}\} =A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be a non-negative matrix, such that:

1. $a_{i,i} = 0 ~~ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
2. $a_{i,j} \geq 0 ~~ \forall i \neq j$

Given the previous hypotheses and using the Perron-Frobenius theorem (or also other results), can I claim one of the following statements?

1. There exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda > 0$
2. There exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \geq 0$

Comment: You can not claim the first, for example $a_{i,j} = 0$ for all $i,j$ certainly satisfies your hypotheses, however it has only 0 eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It can not be claimed, as the zero matrix satisfies both 1. and 2.
2. This can be claimed using Perron-Frobenius (rather using the idea of its proof), since, it $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax\ne 0$, for every $x\in \mathbb R^n\{0\}$ with non-negative elements. Take 
   $$
   f(x)=\frac{Ax}{\ell(Ax)},
   $$
   where $$\ell(x_1,\ldots,x)=x_1+\cdots+x_n,
   $$
   Then $f : \Delta^{n-1}\to\Delta^{n-1}$, is a continuous map, where $\Delta^{n-1}$ is the simplex $$\Delta^{n-1}=\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n): \ell x=1, x_i\ge 0\},$$ and thus it has a fixed point (according to Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem, as the closed simplex is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$):
   $$
   f(x)=x, 
   $$
   or
   $$
   Ax=\ell(Ax)x.
   $$
   This means that $x$ is an eigenvector and $\ell(Ax)>0$, the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: just a last question. In which point of your proof do you make use of Perron-Frobenius theorem? Thank you again!

Comment: I did not use Perron-Frobenius, but I did use the idea of its proof. And the idea is the definition of the functional on the simplex and the use of Brouwer's FPT.

Comment: Ok. I'm a little bit confused because searching around, I found that Perron-Frobenius theorem is valid only for positive matrix, while this is non-negative. It seems like that your demonstration is something that does not exist in literature! Am I right and you proved an unknown theorem?